# Apache VHost redirect aliases to HTTPS

Tags: virtualhost, mod-rewrite, apache2, lets-encrypt, ubuntu-20.04

I'm trying to do Virtualhosts on my "playground" VPS.

I need it to redirect 3 or more domains to the main one.

Also it should redirect HTTPS, Lets Encrypt is configured and working well.

In current state, this config works fine, BUT when user goes to HTTPS secsite.com manually (entering HTTPS himself), it redirects to mainsite first and then redirects again back to secsite.com.

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
        ServerName mainsite.com
        ServerAlias *.mainsite.com secsite.com *.secsite.com

        RewriteRule !https:\/\/mainsite\.com https://mainsite.com%{REQUEST_URI} [END,NE,R=permanent]
</VirtualHost>

<IfModule mod_ssl.c>
<VirtualHost *:443>
        ServerName mainsite.com
        ServerAlias *.mainsite.com secsite.com *.secsite.com

        RewriteRule !https:\/\/mainsite\.com https://mainsite.com%{REQUEST_URI} [END,NE,R=permanent]

        ServerAdmin webmaster@localhost
        DocumentRoot /var/www/mainsite.com

        ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/error.log
        CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/access.log combined

        SSLCertificateFile /etc/letsencrypt/live/mainsite.com/fullchain.pem
        SSLCertificateKeyFile /etc/letsencrypt/live/mainsite.com/privkey.pem
        Include /etc/letsencrypt/options-ssl-apache.conf
</VirtualHost>
</IfModule>
```

Any idea how to get this work?

Answer (score 1):

> ```
> RewriteRule !https:\/\/mainsite\.com https://mainsite.com%{REQUEST_URI} [END,NE,R=permanent]
> ```

The `RewriteRule` directive matches against the URL-path only, not the scheme + hostname, as you are trying to do here. Since you have negated the *pattern* (`!` prefix), it will *always* be successful and result in a redirect loop. That is, if it is doing anything at all...

You've not enabled the rewrite engine (ie. `RewriteEngine On`), so unless this is enabled earlier in the config, these `RewriteRule` directives are simply going to be ignored.

If you are seeing any redirect at all, either you are seeing a cached response from an earlier attempt (note that 301 redirects are cached persistently by the browser), or your application (or something else) is triggering the redirect.

The redirect in your vHost:80 (HTTP) should be an *unconditional* mod_alias `Redirect`, since you are redirecting everything to HTTPS.  For example:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerName mainsite.com
    ServerAlias *.mainsite.com secsite.com *.secsite.com

    Redirect 301 / https://mainsite.com/
</VirtualHost>
```

The `Redirect` directive is prefix-matching and everything after the match is copied onto the end of the target URL. eg. `http://example.com/foo/bar` is redirected to `https://mainsite/foo/bar`.

For the vHost:443 (HTTPS) you need to redirect when the requested hostname is not the canoncial host. For this you need to use an additional `RewriteCond` directive and check against the `HTTP_HOST` server variable. For example:

```
<IfModule mod_ssl.c>
<VirtualHost *:443>
    ServerName mainsite.com
    ServerAlias *.mainsite.com secsite.com *.secsite.com

    RewriteEngine On
    RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^mainsite\.com$
    RewriteRule ^ https://mainsite.com%{REQUEST_URI} [END,NE,R=permanent]
    :
```